# Show div on tab and onFocus and hide on onBlur

Tags: reactjs

I have a input box where I want to show and hide div on onFocus and onBlur  which is working fine but on when pressing tab on the input box i want the div to be shown but its keep hiding because the focus is keep loosing.

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
handleBlur = (e) => {
    this.setState({showdiv: false});}
handleFocus = (e) => {
    this.setState({showDiv: true});}
<input type="search"
    onFocus={(e) => this.handleFocus(e)}
    onBlur={(e) => this.handleBlur(e)}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showdiv: false
    }
  }
  handleBlur = (e) => {
    this.setState({showdiv: false});}
handleFocus = (e) => {
    this.setState({showDiv: true});
}
onInputKeydown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 9) { // tab value is 9
     this.setState({showDiv: true});
  }
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Hi
        <input type="search"
        onKeyDown={this.onInputKeydown}
    onFocus={(e) => this.handleFocus(e)}
    onBlur={(e) => this.handleBlur(e)}
/>;
      </div>
    );
  }
}

    export default App;
```

You can use onKeyDown event to read the value if tab is pressed when focus is on input field